# Can I make GIMP work as a MacOS X Service?

Tags: services, image-editing

I would like to be able to use GIMP as a MacOS X Service. That is, I want to be able to select an image in a document, choose Services->Edit Image in GIMP, bring the image into GIMP, make changes, save it out, and have the image updated.

The Services menu worked really well in NeXTSTEP but most MacOS X users have no clue what it is for. It would be nice to be able to start using it again.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a service like this with Automator:

[image]

It can't be used to for example edit an image embedded in a Pages document though.

Comment: Can automater make a service that will wait for the file to be edited and then return it? Hm. It might not be that hard to code something up that does what I just described.